# Powershell - Combine two pipelines into one

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, pipeline, pylint

I am using Powershell (version 5.1.17763.1007), and wish to combine two pipelines into one.
Their contents are very similar;
They recursively look for Python files from a folder into it's subfolders,
and generate linting-reports for these Python files, using Pylint and prospector respectively
(see https://www.pylint.org/ and https://pypi.org/project/prospector/ )

```
$path_to_files = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\Desktop\my_project_folder\linter_reports"

# Get all Python modules in folder and generate Pylint reports
Get-ChildItem -Path $path_to_files -Recurse -Filter *.py |
  ForEach-Object { pylint $_.Name |
                   Out-File -FilePath "pylint_results_$($_.Name.TrimEnd(".py")).txt"
                   }

# Get all Python modules in folder and generate Prospector reports
Get-ChildItem -Path $path_to_files -Recurse -Filter *.py |
  ForEach-Object { prospector $_.Name |
                   Out-File -FilePath "prospector_results_$($_.Name.TrimEnd(".py")).txt"
                   }
```

I have experimented with the Tee-Object Cmdlet (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-7), is that the best approach?
I am looking for something like this (pseudo-code):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path_to_files -Recurse -Filter *.py |
  ForEach-Object Tee-Object { pylint $_.Name |
                   Out-File -FilePath "pylint_results_$($_.Name.TrimEnd(".py")).txt"
                   } |
                            { prospector$_.Name |
                   Out-File -FilePath "prospector_results_$($_.Name.TrimEnd(".py")).txt"
                   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not execute the two commands after each other?

```
$path_to_files = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\Desktop\my_project_folder\linter_reports"

# Get all Python modules in folder and generate Pylint and prospector reports
Get-ChildItem -Path $path_to_files -Recurse -Filter *.py |
  ForEach-Object { pylint $_.Name |
                   Out-File -FilePath "pylint_results_$($_.Name.TrimEnd(".py")).txt"

                   prospector $_.Name |
                   Out-File -FilePath "prospector_results_$($_.Name.TrimEnd(".py")).txt"
                   }
```